# Automatically running a python script after boot

Tags: python, boot, script

After a lot of trial and failure to find a solution, i came acros adding the path to a executable script to `/etc/profile` the only problem is that the script only boots on the ssh sessions and not directly on the pi when i plug it in.

How may i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works on Jessie if you want to start an app or script upon logging in to the desktop:

Add these lines in your ~/.profile:

```
(sleep 15 && leafpad) &
```

I'm using 'leafpad' here as an example; insert the path to the app or script you'd like to run.

Here's what this does:

- Sleeps 15 seconds then launches 'leafpad'
- The "&&" means "wait until the command before this finishes".
- The "&" means "do this in the background; continue with the rest of the script containing this line".
- The parentheses group things so the sleep AND the launch are both done in the background.

Because of the last "&" you can actually do several of these lines:

```
(sleep 15 && leafpad) &
(sleep 15 && cheese) &
(sleep 15 && epiphany) &
```

and they will all start a few seconds after you login to the desktop.

NOTE HOWEVER this will ALSO run this app when you ssh in to the RPi; if you are trying to run a desktop app, this may or may not be what you want.  I'll look for away to NOT launch if you are connecting via ssh.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the script inside `/etc/rc.local`.

If you have Raspbian 7 Wheezy, that should work out of the box. With Raspbian 8 Jessie, you might need to enabled systemd's `rc-local.service` (according to [this forum posting](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/rc-local-systemd-938456/#post4702737)).

Comment: I'm running Raspbian Jessie, How may i enable ´rc-local.service´ ? Calling the script from inside ´/etc/rc.local´ without enabling ´rc-local.service´ it doesn't run the script. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/299506/389434 for such a file and its location.

Comment: to acsess /etc/rc.local run

Comment: sudo leafpad /etc/rc.local

Comment: not sure why it split that up into 2 comments. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As the script that i was trying to execute at everyboot of the pi needed another programs to boot before it execution, i solved the problem by adding a sleep time. The added lines to the `/etc/profiles` file looks like this:

```
sleep 1m
/path/to/myexecutablescript
```